# Synaptics Touchpad not working after a fresh install of 12.04.2 on a Toshiba P850

Tags: 12.04, installation, touchpad, toshiba

I have read all related posts I can find but none of them offer a solution.

The touch-pad is detected but does not work.  It works in Windows 8 (machine is dual boot)

```
$ egrep -i touchpad syslog
May 18 20:44:35 node7 kernel: [   10.787917] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x126c00
May 18 20:44:35 node7 kernel: [   10.893065] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input10
May 19 09:24:36 node7 kernel: [   11.728268] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x126c00
May 19 09:24:36 node7 kernel: [   11.861941] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input12
May 19 09:36:21 node7 kernel: [   11.646728] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x126c00
May 19 09:36:21 node7 kernel: [   11.776112] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input11
```

In particular this does not work, it just causes compiz to crash and restart:

```
$ sudo modprobe -r psmouse
$ sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
May 19 09:48:12 node7 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" 
x-pid="1101" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
May 19 09:48:42 node7 rsyslogd: last message repeated 2 times
May 19 09:49:41 node7 gnome-session[2106]: WARNING: Application 'compiz.desktop' killed by signal
May 19 09:49:41 node7 gnome-session[2106]: WARNING: App 'compiz.desktop' respawning too quickly
May 19 09:49:41 node7 gnome-session[2106]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
May 19 09:49:50 node7 anacron[1249]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
May 19 09:49:50 node7 anacron[1249]: Normal exit (1 job run)
May 19 09:50:09 node7 kernel: [  844.392522] input: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input16
May 19 09:50:51 node7 kernel: [  886.068210] type=1400 audit(1368953451.556:35): 
apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1194 comm="cupsd" pid=1194 comm="cupsd" capability=36  capname="block_suspend"
```

Comment: This issue is now resolved since a recent Ubuntu update. Not sure which update it was but thanks guys & girls :)